# Dual supply on/off switch quesiton

Tags: power-supply

I've made a dual supply using two 9V batteries, and I want to make an on/off switch for it. I know how switches are connected with single batteries, but I'm not sure how is it done with dual supply. Here is a picture of the dual supply connection.

[image]

Any idea on where the switch should be connected?

Comment: Use a double-pole switch, one pole on the +9V, the other on the -9V line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a double-pole switch (DPST or DPDT), wired like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHvNoX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I only have SPDT switches at the moment, can I make two of those one for each pole?...this is of course until I get the DPST switch.

Comment: Yes - you can use two separte single-pole switches, but you must reemember to turn them off or on together.

Comment: I just found a DPDT switch, I tested it and it's working,thank you very much!